# Too much aliasing on normal map

Tags: texture-baking, normals, baking

I have these two models:

[image]

As you can see, they're the same base, but one has a lace running on the hilt. Now I baked a normal map (because the lace is about 120k poly, pretty impractical I think), here's the result:

[image]

(The normal is 4k, probably overkill but I'm experimenting)

There are two problems:

1) The lace is too aliased. You can clearly see the aliasing of the normal if you're close to the hilt.

2) Minor, but still, on the circle and the simbol, there are those bumps that should not be there, I think. Keep in mind the only thing that's different in these two models is the lace, the ring and the simbols have the same number of faces, that's why I think those bumps are some kind of errors. They were way worse before, playing with the bias and the distance settings in the baking menu (I used standard blender to bake the normal) reduced but did not fix them completely.

The end result looks pretty good (viewed from a distance) and those bumps on the ring aren't really visible:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You could get anti-aliased normal maps by scaling your 4k map to a 1k map, I believe this would give you an AA equivalent of 2, but I am unsure on that. You could also use a dedicated baking software like [xnormal](http://www.xnormal.net/1.aspx).

Comment: what that is mean "AA" 2x2 subsampling?